# Open new view clicking on DataGrid element (WPF xaml application)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have WPF application written using MVVM architecture, so I have Model, View and ViewModel. I have a `DataGrid` in my View that contains the list of `Product`s (that contains several fields: name, balance and so on).

I want to add additional window/view, that will appear after clicking on the element in the `DataGrid`. Is it possible? If so, how?

I'm interesting in xaml code, not in something like `button1_Click`.

That's what I have at the moment:

```
<Window ...
    Height="600" Width="800"
    WindowState="Maximized">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              CanUserResizeRows="False"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentProduct, Mode=TwoWay}"
              >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ProductName}"
                                Header="Product Name"
                                Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Balance}"
                                Header="Balance"
                                Width="Auto" />
            ...
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: So...You want to call a command that opens another view from your datagrid click, am I right?

Comment: @Kirenenko All ideas are welcome. Using a command is okay too.

Comment: You can also look this tutorial for DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplatel:  http://www.wpftutorial.net/datagrid.html

Comment: @Ugur Yeah, you're right, RowDetailsTemplate is very useful feature, but unfortunately I can't use it in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fire a command when you RightClick on some element of the datagrid:

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding
        MouseAction="RightClick"
        Command="{Binding yourCommand,Mode=OneWay}"
    />
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

Run new view:

```
var win = new Window();
win.Content = new yourNewViewModel();
win.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight; //Adjust window size to content
win.Show();
```

You must link yourNewViewModel with yourNewView, in App.xaml:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type yourProjectViewModel:yourNewViewModel}">
    <local:yourNewView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Dont forget to add the xmlns of yourProjectViewModel to your App.xaml

Comment: Thanks, it will be helpful. But... How i can run new view?